# Need help decoding JSON output with PHP

Tags: php, json, google-maps, variables, decode

Here is the sample JSON output I am working with:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:90210&sensor=false
```

Here is the attempt to pull the latitude value from this location:

```
$postalLong = $jsonOutput>results[0]->formatted_address[0]->location[1]->lng;
```

I have tried several variations but it is not working.  How can I have this apply the `34.1030032` value to this variable?

Comment: How about `$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have mismatched it. Try this -

```
$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```